# mysqli query delete

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have all data from a database table display as an HTML table on a page. 
When an admin selects a row, it adds a class of 'remove' to the parent row in the HTML table.

I then want to delete it from the mysqli database. Would I set the row fields as variables and delete the row that matches it in the database? I'm not sure how to do it, could someone please point me in the right direction?

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr class="remove">
    <td>field1</td>
    <td>field2</td>
    <td>field3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another field</td>
    <td>another field</td>
    <td>another field</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Mysqli (relevant sample)

```
  $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE Date="??" LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: I am really not sure of what you are trying to say but I think you need to set some unique id to each row while you are displaying the table and then you can delete that particular selected row with that id

Comment: Yeh that sounds about right. But I'm not sure how to setup the IDs or then how to use the HTMl to select a particular ID.

Comment: There must be a primary key column in your table. When you fetch records make the value from primary key the name of your select box you use to delete or something else...then you can always get that value "on click" and fire a delete query in database.

Comment: Ah OK. Yes I have a column with dates in that is the primary key column. But there are some rows where the date is the same in both. Won't that cause a problem when I try to select a row because the entry in the primary column isn't unique?

Comment: you mean date is your primary column and you don't have unique entries in it...that's so not possible....try having primary key as some auto increment column

Comment: The dates in the date column are input by the admin so if the admin puts the same date on 2 entries, there will be 2 rows with the same date. Primary key on auto increment column could work but am I able to add a column/field to an existing table? I can't see how to do that either.

Comment: Scrap my previous comment I've worked out how to add another field.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `JavaScript`, which I assume you are as you're adding a class to a row when it's selected, you could do the following:

**1. Include a hidden disabled input in each row:**

```
<tr class="remove">
    <td>field1</td>
    <td>field2</td>
    <td>

        field3

        <input type="hidden" disabled name="delete[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

    </td>
</tr>
```

**2. Enable the hidden input when it is selected to be removed:**

I'm not going to guess how you're adding the `remove` class to the row, but when doing so have it remove the `disabled` attribute of the hidden `delete[]` input contained within it.

**3. Post the form:**

Once posted you can run the query to delete all the rows with an ID in the `$_POST['delete']` array.

If you're using prepared statements you can use the following query where `?` is `implode(',', $_POST['delete'])`:

```
"DELETE FROM " . $table . " WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, ?) != 0"
```

I'm assuming here for the sake of simplicity that you have a unique `id` field (that doesn't contain `,`s as part of its value). Obviously change to whatever is relevant for your database.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a solution similar to this. I had a hidden input on each row where the value was the unique ID (set in the table using auto increment). Then when a row was selected for deletion, I used jQuery to select the input on that row. Finally I did "WHERE ID="$rowID" to locate the correct row and delete it.